# React and CSS gauge progress. SVG circular path length

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg

How to make a percentage based length for red(see codepen ) stroke?
also wanted to use same item in react so % value for the red stroke need to add dynamically.
wanted to make a gauge progress based on attached image, please help

```
  <svg id="paths">
    <path d="M100 100 A 40 40 90 0 1 250 100" 
        style="fill: transparent;
            fill-opacity: 1;
            stroke: gray;
            stroke-width: 15;  stroke-linecap:round;" />
 <path d="M100 100 A 40 40 90 0 1 250 100" 
        style="fill: transparent;
            fill-opacity: 1;
            stroke: red;
            stroke-width: 8;  stroke-linecap:round;" />
  </svg>
```

Css only Svg
https://codepen.io/anoopsuda/pen/yLpgLpw
React Svg
https://codesandbox.io/s/fancy-hooks-xxvxkh?file=/src/Gauge.js

[image]

Answer (score 2):

just run the snippet, just set `stroke-dasharray: expect total`the `total` length you can get from `document.queryselector('your path').getTotalLength()`, and `expect` is `0.5*total` for 50%

```html
<svg 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     version="1.1"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
  <svg id="paths">
    <path d="M100 100 A 40 40 90 0 1 250 100" 
        style="fill: transparent;
            fill-opacity: 1;
            stroke: gray;
            stroke-width: 25;  stroke-linecap:round;" />
 <path d="M100 100 A 40 40 90 0 1 250 100" 
        style="fill: transparent;
            fill-opacity: 1;
            stroke: red;
            stroke-dasharray: 117.826 300;
            stroke-width: 16;  stroke-linecap:round;" />
  </svg>
 
</svg>
```

---

I built a component for react, `react-svg-path-percentage`, and here is the example usage
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-svg-path-percentage-0eupiq?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is a good approach. One tiny improvement you can make is to add a `pathLength` of 100 to the path. That way you won't have to do the extra work of getting the `getTotalLength`. Now  the stroke-dasharray can be set to `50 100`

Comment: @Shreshth good to know that, thanks!